# 3D Point and Vectors - Why don't I have System.Windows.Media.Media3D and should I use it?

Tags: c#, 3d

I want to represent a 3d location and a 3d direction of travel in a little learning project I am doing. I google up "C# 3D Point" to see if something exists before I go making my own and I came up with Point3D and Vector3D from System.Windows.Media.Media3D, however when I go to add a reference, it isn't there. It also talks about how it is for WPF applications.

So, Why don't I have that assemble available?...and should I even be using it?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.media3d.vector3d?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: How about using a [`Vector3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead?

Comment: @Diado Sounds fine with me, if that's the thing to do! I do wonder why the other assembly doesn't exist on my machine though.

Comment: According to the docs you linked to, those namespaces/classes are in the PresentationCore.dll so that is what you should reference.  If you created a WPF application, it should already be referenced.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I'm just running a console app. Ok that makes sense then. Thanks! If either of you fellas would like to make an answer I can mark this answered.